# Replace month year with year month

Tags: mysql, notepad++

I have a mySQL database with about 800 rows that contain the titel

Post Month Year

For example: Post September 2012

This causes a problem when sorting the data output and it would be better if the data was:

Post Year Month

I have found topics where you can export the mysql database and change mm-yy into yy-mm with Notepad++ but those are all numbers.

Is there an option, within mysql notepad++ or another tool, to bulk change Month Year to Year Month?

Comment: Are those in a different column or the same one ?

Comment: This is a single column right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a regex and replace for all occurrences. You can do this in Notepad++, if you like. Like this:

Find: `Post (\w+) (\d{4})`

Replace: `Post \2 \1`

EDIT: Another option would be to create a custom comparator for these fields while sorting, that allows you to keep your current data as it is.

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much, you just saved me hours of work.

Comment: How would it work to turn 2012-1-19 in to 19 Jan 2012? Is there a tutorial for such functions?

Comment: For a quick result I would run 12 regex replaces on the file. Find: `(\d{4})-1-(\d{1,2})` and Replace: `\2 Jan \1`. Repeat this for all the months in the year and you are set. If you need a better solution, you could write a script to do this for you. But that will be a bit more complex.

Comment: Unfortunatly I cannot find a how to for this, but perhaps you know how to do it. Replace this <time>2012-3-15 12:25:56</time> with <time>2012-3-15 10:25:56</time><timegmt>2012-3-15 10:25:56</timegmt>
Replacing all date between <time>DATA</time> with <time>DATA</time><timegmt>DATE minus 2 hours</timegmt>. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If anyone else has similar problems http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions is a great site for learing.

Comment: I'm afraid regex can't help you there. You need to solve this programmatically, because dates are tricky. Minus 2 hours often means a lot more, than just decrementing the hour number of the date.

Answer (score 2):

you can do that in two step first create function that splits the string using following statement::: i got this statement from http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

now assuming your table name is test and the field that holds the data is dates you can run following query :::

```
UPDATE test SET dates = CONCAT('POST ', (SELECT SPLIT_STR(dates, ' ', 3)), ' ', (SELECT SPLIT_STR(dates, ' ', 2)));
```